# Element UI - VueJS

Tags: vue.js, element-ui

when using `el-dropdown` of https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/dropdown, how do I trigger the dropdown or hide it with code, when `split-button` is `true`? I can do it easily when I was using `React` and `bootstrap` with `ref` or bootstrap control

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that by adding a `ref` to `el-dropdown` element.

```
<el-dropdown ref="dropdownElement" split-button type="primary" @click="handleClick">
```

Then, In the `handleClick()` method you can access the `split-button` flag `true`/`false` and then do the code as per your requirement.

```
if (this.$refs.dropdownElement.splitButton) {
  // write your code here
}
```